# Trying to understand integration by parts

Tags: integration

I am trying to understand integration by parts and for learning purposes I tried to solve this integrand in a non-standard way. But it's wrong. I can't see why however.

$$\int{xe^x dx}=\int x\frac{d(e^x)}{dx}dx=\int x\times d(e^x)$$

Now we could take $u=e^x$ So:

$$\int x\times d(e^x)=\int xdu=xu=xe^x$$

But the right answer is:

$$\int{xe^x dx}=(x-1)e^x$$

So apparently I made a mistake. What is the mistake? And is it possible to solve this integrand following this procedure if fixed?

Comment: Your error is in going from $\int x du$ to $xu$.  "x" is **not** constant with respect to u.  Since you defined $u= e^x$, $x= ln(u)$.  $\int x du= \int ln(u)du$.

Comment: You don't seem to be using integration by parts at all. All I see here is a u-substitution.

Comment: Integration by parts only says if $w(t) = u(t)v(t)$ then $w'(t) = u'(t)v(t)+u(t)v'(t)$ and hence $w(b)-w(a)=\int_a^b w'(t)dt=\int_a^b u'(t)v(t)dt+\int_a^b u(t)v'(t)dt$. Change of variable follows the same lines with $h(t) = f(g(t))$, $\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f'(u)du = f(g(b))-f(g(a)) = h(b)-h(a) = \int_a^b h'(t) =\int_a^b  f'(g(t))g'(t)dt$

Comment: @reuns That's a neat explanation (much better than how it was taught to me) and of course the two techniques use some of the same ideas--there are only a few big ideas in calculus. I'm just saying I expect to see both $u'v\,dt$ and $uv'\,dt$ in one equation in an integration by parts, and I don't see them written out in the question. We can help OP by pointing out the error in their substitution method, but that won't help OP understand what integration by parts is.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how integration by parts was described to you,
so I'll try a couple of different descriptions.
The formula that I was first taught was
$$
\int u \,dv = uv - \int v\,du.
$$

A less compact (but less potentially misleading) way to write this is
$$
\int_a^b u(t) v'(t)\,dt = u(b)v(b) - u(a)v(b) - \int_a^b v(t) u'(t)\,dt.
$$

I'm sure there are other ways to write integration by parts, but the thing that makes it an integration by parts is that we find a function
$f(t) = u(t)v(t)$ to which we can differentiate according to the product rule, $f(t) = u'(t)v(t) + u(t)v'(t),$ so that $u(t)v'(t)$ matches the integrand that we wish to integrate.

Your attempt used the symbol $u$ where I would have used $v.$
That doesn't really matter--the formulas for integration by parts are just as true if you swap all the $u$s with the $v$s--but all the same I find that
once I have learned a technique using a certain set of symbols,
it helps me to use the same symbols the same way (if I can)
each time I apply the technique.
So let's set $v = e^x,$ so that
$$
\int xe^x\, dx = \int x\left(\frac{d}{dx}e^x\right)dx
= \int x\frac{dv}{dx} \,dx = \int x\,dv.
$$

Now, technically for this particular integration we could proceed to write an integration by parts using the variable $x$ instead of introducing a new variable, $u,$ but for the sake of "using the same symbols in the same way,"
let's set $u = x$ anyway. So we now have
$$
\int xe^x\, dx = \int u\,dv.
$$

Integration by parts tells us that
\begin{align}
\int u \,dv &= uv - \int v\,du \\
&= xe^x - \int e^x \,dx \\
&= xe^x - e^x \\
&= (x - 1)e^x.
\end{align}